Free module and finitely generated submodule.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $M$ a free $A$-module and $N\subseteq M$ a finitely generated submodule.
Prove that there is a Sub-Noetherian Ring $A_0 \subseteq A$, a free $A_0$-submodule $M_0 \subseteq M$ and a finetily generated $A_0$-module $N_0 \subseteq M_0$ such that $M=AM_0$ and $N=AN_0$.

So, I am a little bit overwhelmed, with this statement, so if some one could help me splitting this in some affirmations that I can prove to conclude the exersice it will be very helpful, thanks.

Hint: Choose a basis ${e_i}_{i\in I}$ of $M$. Pick a finite set of generators of $N$ and write each one of them as a finite sum $\sum a_ie_i$ where the coefficients are in $A$. Now let $A_0$ be the subring generated by all these coefficients. Try to continue from here.

Oh! thanks a lot, I will continue from there!
